# Problems with position:fixed and responsive / adaptive Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

First look at this website: http://irismediainfo2.lili.de/spip.php?article4924

On my screen it looks like on this screenshot: [chrome - full window - desktop resolution: 1440x900](http://www.iris-media.info/IMG/png/7/5/f/toolbar_on_my_screen.png)
I think for most of you it will look diferent but thats part of the problem...

The main div with the gray border is inside an other div with id="page".

```
    #page {
        width: 560px;
        margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
        position:relative;
        }
```

I created a new div with id="toolbar", that looks like it sticks to this #page-div, but it does not scroll with the page. On the website I linked above u can see the #toolbar as a dummy-box (grey with some Text).

At the moment the I use `position:fixed` in #toolbar.

When I position it at the side of #page so that it LOOKS like it is attached to it, and I resize the browser window... the two divs dont move the same way because the position of #page is calculated from the middle (by margin:auto) and the position of #toolbar is calculated from the side of the browser window (by position:fixed). So it is not attatched anymore in any other windowsizes.

I tried to make the #page float, to make the #toolbar appear at the side but that destroys the "margin:auto" of the #page so it is not centered anymore.

I also tried

```
#toolbar {
    position: fixed;
    center: 0px;  }
```

Because I hoped there could be a way to calculate the position for `position:fixed` from the center.

Nothing worked, I hope you know a solution.
Actually everything I want is something like:

```
    #page {
        width: 560px;
        margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
        position:relative;  }

    #toolbar {
        position: fixed;
        center: 0px 280px 0px 0px;  }
```

I would like to do this with minimal code and resources because I don't want to make the loading speed worse because of a little toolbar.

If you need more specific code from my css or html please tell me.
I hope the target and the problem is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a wrapper-div that centers the whole block and algin the toolbar after that, since your `#page` has a fixed width in every viewport.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="toolbar">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#toolbar {
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 15px;
    background-color: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto 0px 279px;
}
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Logic at its finest.
Very simple. :D thx a lot.

Never thought of splitting the css properties like that. Very usefull. :)

Comment: Maybe you have another simple answer for a problem I just found:

when you hover the toolbar you see the background changes its opacity. but then it jumps back to its start-value. why?

Comment: You need to add the styles that get applied after the animation is done
`#toolbar:hover {background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170); animation: 1s ease 0s normal none 1 running fadein;}`

Comment: Whoop Whoop. Easy.
First experience in stackoverflow are so good that I will annoy you with other problems soon. :)

Comment: Sure thing, do that x)

Comment: I have the same issue but in my responsive view that `wrapper` 'position: fixed;` is not solving the problem.